# Listbox only sorts on first digit

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox

I am deserializing a textfile that holds records and am casting the records into an Product object. I add the objects to a listbox and sort by the first field, which is Price and is set as a double. I set the listbox to sort:

```
listBox1.Sorted = true;
```

But the listbox only sorts on the first digit, i.e., it places $15.00 above $3.00. What would be the best way to sort by the whole price and not just the first digit?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012647/custom-listbox-sorting

Answer (score 1):

The probleme is it doesn't sort numericly but alphabetically, 
please set `listBox1.Sorted = false;`
Begin sorting your Product list by price with [sort method](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727/en-us) then add each element to the control.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will have to derive from ListBox in order to do so. Overriding its `void Sort()` method will do the trick:

```
public class AlphabeticalSortedListBox : ListBox {
    public AlphabeticalSortedListBox() : base() {
        Sorted = true;
    }

    protected override void Sort() {
        // apply your sorting algorithm on this.Items here.
        // You might want to use an algorithm that does well
        // in the best case (e.g. insertion sort [O(n)] to make it easy)
        // because in the common situation we have an almost sorted list of Items
    }
}
```